# Proper use of 'alcohol', 'alcohol-content', and 'abv' tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've noticed that the [alcohol](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol), [alcohol-content](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol-content), and [abv](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abv) tags are all used on a similar range of questions.

The [alcohol-content](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol-content) and [abv](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abv) tags seem to be very related and basically synonyms in many, if not all cases.  The [alcohol](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol) tag, though used on many of the same posts, seems to often take on additional meaning, regarding the flavor or other effects caused by the presence of alcohol.

Given that only [abv](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abv) has a wiki excerpt and it is potentially the most unnecessarily specific, I propose one of the following:

1. Make [alcohol](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol) more limited to questions regarding the flavor and other effects of (higher) alcohol concentrations while making [abv](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abv) a synonym of [alcohol-content](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol-content) which should be generally about determining the amount of alcohol in a wine, beer, cider, etc.
2. Make the [abv](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abv) and [alcohol-content](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol-content) tags both synonyms of [alcohol](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol) which would apply to all questions relating to (high) alcohol content, it's calculation, and it's effects.

I think I'm personally in favor of (2) for simplicity's sake though I could see the argument that it would join two fairly different types of questions.

Regardless, I think these tags need (clearer) excerpts to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added excerpts for both alcohol and alcohol content; subject to approval. I do not have the rep in those tags to create synonyms. 
But, I agree that abv <==> alcohol-content should be made synonymous.

Comment: Given you're a moderator now, you can create that synonym - and merge the tags - yourself...